# determine issued rowCommand by command name

Tags: extjs, grid, command, ext.net

I have two row commands running on a gridpanel like the following:

```
<ext:CommandColumn>
   <Commands>
      <ext:GridCommand Icon="NoteEdit" CommandName="mailEdit">
          <ToolTip Text="Edit" />
      </ext:GridCommand>
      <ext:GridCommand Icon="ApplicationLightning" CommandName="mailChangeBlock">
           <ToolTip Text="block/unblock" />
      </ext:GridCommand>                               
   </Commands>                               
</ext:CommandColumn>
```

now i listen to these row commands:

```
<Listeners>
    <Command Handler="if(command == 'mailEdit'){mailEdit}else{mailChangeBlock}; console.log(command);"/>
</Listeners>
```

another try was following:

```
<Command Handler="(command == 'mailEdit') ? mailEdit : mailChangeBlock;" />
```

the console log is executed without problems, but a console.log in the function called is not executed, even though the function gets called as soon as you add brackets to each call, but then the data passed to the function is lost.

my question is now, how can i determine which command was executed and call a corresponding function and give value, metadata and record to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to send the Command name and other values by Extra Params:

```
<DirectEvents>
   <Command OnEvent="GridCommand">
      <ExtraParameters>
         <ext:Parameter Name="commandname" Value="command" Mode="Raw" />
         <ext:Parameter Name="recordid" Value="record.data.id" Mode="Raw" />
      </ExtraParameters>
   </Command>
</DirectEvents>
```

the determination of command can then be executed server-sided (`command` returns the `CommandName` defined in the `CommandColumn`) and then execute server-sided script.